# Browsermob causes error in IntelliJ created jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, executable-jar, browsermob

I'm trying to create executable jar for Maven Selenium/TestNG/Java test automation project, but I keep getting "Error: Could not find or load main class" when running .jar file. 
To make sure it is indeed Browsermob causing jar to fail, I created a new maven project, which has a single file in src\main\java directory

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("works");    
    }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ and when create .jar (Project Structure > Artifacts > JAR > From modules... etc) without Browsermob dependency everything is fine.
But as soon as I add Browsermob to it .jar starts to fail with "Error: Could not find or load main class".

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Test2
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test2
```

Other dependencies don't seem to cause any trouble.

pom.xml just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>JarTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>gpn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For packaging a runnable plugin in Maven you need a dedicated plugin.
There are many you can choose between, look [here](http://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) for more info, or also [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

Comment: Thank you! The 1st link actually helped.

Comment: Although now I added `TestNG testng = new TestNG();` in main method (also testng dependency to pom) and it fails with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG at Test2.main`, but I guess it's a different problem

Comment: Yes it's differet; if the answer was helpful please upvote and flag as valid answer :)

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation for my upvote to count apparently( sorry about that!